# Learning more about componentDidMount and its warning on the console

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I don't know why, but I'm seeing the following warning when I'm running my React application:

```
react-dom.development.js:12357 Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See *documentation* for details.

* Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.
* Rename componentWillMount to UNSAFE_componentWillMount to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: SideEffect(NullComponent)
```

I'm getting confused because I'm not using this lifecycle method. Instead, I'm using useEffect, useMemo and useState hooks in my code. I wish I had some way of get rid of this warning.

Comment: Are you using other dependency in this component? Please also share your component code.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this warning. It was because I was using react-router-dom and react-select which was internally using componentWillUnmount that was the cause of the warning.

**What did I do?**

First I did `npm update` for the affected modules.

But still, there were other modules that had not released new versions. So in order to get rid of this warning and see a relevant warning, I did `console.disableYellowBox = true;`

This was purely for my case.

In case if you don't know these warnings, they will only be shown in development mode and not in production. See documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html).